# Drop-down select option with filter and navigation by keys

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I want to build a dropdown select option menu with filter and I want to be able to filter by keys and use Enter key to select or to use the mouse in order to select.

The code I wrote is bellow and I am stuck. How can I make the options act just like I am using mouse and click when I filter and use arrow keys and enter? I hope you understand me, English is not my first language.

Should I rethink the code? I want to use pure javascript, so jQuery or other framework wont help.

Thanks for your help.

I created a jsfiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/rscj2tuv/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  .dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
  }
  #myInput {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  #myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
  .dropdown a:focus {background-color: #ddd;}
  .show {display: block;}
  .selected {
    background:#efefef;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>
  <input name='fname' type='text' placeholder='220' value='' readonly="readonly" size='1'>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><span id="ajaxify">Dropdown</span></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" style="height: 200px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myInput"  onkeyup="filterFunction()">
      <a onclick="toyFunction('22','About')">About</a>
      <a onclick="toyFunction('32','Base')">Base</a>
      <a onclick="toyFunction('42','Blog')">Blog</a>
      <a onclick="toyFunction('52','Go')">Go</a>
      <a onclick="toyFunction('62','Out')">Out</a>
      <a onclick="toyFunction('72','Now')">Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span id="ajaxify1">Dropdown</span>
  <script>
  function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    document.getElementById("myInput").focus();
  }
  function toyFunction(cat,name) {
    xx = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    xx.classList.toggle("show");
    document.getElementsByName('fname')[0].value=cat;
    document.getElementById("ajaxify").innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
    a = xx.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      a[i].style.display = "block";

    }
    loadXmlDoc(cat);
  }
  function loadXmlDoc(fname){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("ajaxify1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "post.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("fname=" + fname);
  }
  function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
  xx = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var a = xx.getElementsByTagName("a");
  var options = Array.from(xx.getElementsByTagName("a")).map(function(el){
    return el.innerHTML;
  });

  var zz='0';
  xx = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var a = xx.getElementsByTagName("a");
  var options = Array.from(a).map(function(el){
    return el.innerHTML;
  });
  input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
      var a = options.filter(function(a){
        return a.toLowerCase().includes(input.value.toLowerCase());
      });
      if(a.length > 0){
    xx = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    xx.classList.toggle("show");
    document.getElementsByName('fname')[0].value=a[zz];
    document.getElementById("ajaxify").innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
    a = xx.getElementsByTagName("a");
      }
    }
  });
  input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      a[zz].style.cssText = '';
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
      ++zz;
      if(zz==options.length){
        zz='0';
      }
      a[zz].style.backgroundColor = '#ddd';
      document.getElementsByName('fname')[0].value=options[zz];
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 38){
      --zz;
      if(zz<'0'){
        zz=options.length-1;
      }
      a[zz].style.backgroundColor = '#ddd';
      document.getElementsByName('fname')[0].value=options[zz];
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten the script and it works. This is the link to the script.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235178/drop-down-menu-with-autofilter-and-click-enter-for-selection-and-navigation-by-m